# How to prepare a procedure stored in MySQL to export tables with a 'dynamic path'?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a procedure stored in MySQL to export tables with a dynamic route, but when I execute "CALL export_data ('data2018', 'e: Datos.csv')" I get an error, it seems that the path must be between 'quotes' but I have no idea how to put those quotes to the '?' so that it does not stop being variable, hopefully someone can help me solve this problem, thanks

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE export_data (name VARCHAR(25), path VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SET @tableName = name;
    SET @pathName = path;
    SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT AP,AM,Nom,DNI,Direc INTO OUTFILE ? FIELDS 
        TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" FROM `',@tableName,'` 
        ORDER BY AP ASC');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @pathName;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use ascii character 39 where single quotes are needed. And I don't see the need for user defined variables.

```
drop procedure if exists p;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p (name VARCHAR(25), path VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT AP,AM,Nom,DNI,Direc INTO OUTFILE ',char(39),path,char(39),' FIELDS 
        TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" FROM ' ,char(39),name,char(39),
        ' ORDER BY AP ASC');
     select @q;

   # PREPARE stmt from @q;
   # EXECUTE stmt ;
   # DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```